# ArcPy - Select by Attribute for string doesn't work

Tags: arcpy, query, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I am developing a Python script, in which I want to select features based on an attribute, which is a string. I tried for hours and used a hundred different ways, but I always get the Error 000358 that the query statement is not correct.

I work with a feature class, not shapefile. Assume that my field is called "Fruit" and the value I want to select is "Apple".
What I already tried:

```
whereClause = """"{} = {}""".format("Fruit", "'Apple'")
whereClause = """"{} = '{}'""".format("Fruit", "Apple")
whereClause = """"{0} = '{1}'""".format("Fruit", "Apple")

fruit = "Fruit"
value = "Apple"
whereClause = """"{} = '{}'""".format(fruit, value)

arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(myFeatureClass, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

I also did some other Select By Attribute queries, but always using Integer or other numeric fields and I never had problems. Seems that I cannot get it to work with strings.

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 718, in execute
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 8754, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 8751, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(*gp_fixargs((in_layer_or_view, selection_type, where_clause, invert_where_clause), True)))
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 511, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:  ERROR 000358: Invalid expression. Error with executing of SelectLayerByAttribute.
```

Comment: whereClause ="{} = {}".format("Fruit", "'Apple'") should work. Are you getting any error messages or just no selection? Is your data in a file or enterprise geodatabase? Shapefiles and personal geodatabase SQL isn't case sensitive but file and enterprise geodatabase SQL is. Is there a chance your values for the Fruit field contains leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: The whereClause does not work. I always get an error message, I put it in the question. My data is in a file geodatabase. No, there are no whitespaces, I checked that.

Comment: Try this: whereClause = "{} = '{}'".format("Fruit", "Apple")

Comment: I tried it but it also results in the same error. As I populate the "Fruit" field, at the beginnung all values are set to <Null>. But I just tried and changed that before the Select query to an empty field, so also NULL values should not be a problem.

Comment: Are you trying to select from a feature class or layer? myFeatureClass isn't defined in the snippet. I suspect you need to make feature layer https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000 from your feature class first as layers support selection but feature classes do not.

Comment: Yes I work with a feature class. But I already did some Select By Attributes on the myFeatureClass feature class, not for strings, but for integer fields and that worked. How can that be?

Comment: It shouldn't work, tables and feature classes (IStandaloneTable and IFeatureClass) don't have the necessary interface to hold a selection (ISelection and ISelectionSet) but table view and feature layer (ITableView and IFeatureLayer) do have the necessary interfaces to implement a selection. Either will work for the purposes of an update, insert or search cursor. Is your operation working now that you've created a feature layer object?

Comment: That's strange, I did more than 10 Select by Attribute queries on the same feature class with Integer fields and it works. And I just tried to use the string queries (all variations) for a shapefile I just created from the feature class. I get the same error message, that the query does not work. I will now try to convert it to a feature layer. But in the end, I do not want to keep the feature layer. Can I then convert it back to a feature class?

Comment: Feature layers are just another way of looking at the feature class, no conversion is required - changes made to the rows of the layer are actually changing in the feature class. It's and abstract concept which makes more sense from the ArcObjects side, just as edits made in ArcMap are altering the feature class directly - ArcMap has the role as *the other way of looking at the data*.

Comment: I just converted the feature class to a feature layer, but it still gives me the same error. Maybe I will switch from querying a string to querying a number, as this always worked until now. But actually I would like to find out how to query strings, it cannot be that it doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120360/discussion-between-michael-stimson-and-gis-usar).

Comment: I am really sorry, I cannot join the chat, as I am at work and the access to the chat website is restricted. Sorry for that. I just cannot understand, why it does not work. I am working with GIS for 10 years now and I did a lot of programming. Now I am dealing with this issue for hours

Comment: Do you have any other idea? So now I tried shapefile, feature class, feature layer. For all of these a Select by Attribute query works for integer fields, but not for string fields. I tried all possible combinations of defining the string.

Comment: That is *really* odd, can you try selecting in model builder and export to a python snippet https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000031000000 then see if the snippet runs... it's beginning to look like this is a reinstall situation before contacting Esri support.

Comment: From my working code as you can't access chat DefQ = "NRN = 'xxx0103'" AOI_Layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(area_of_interest, 'AOI') arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('AOI', 'NEW_SELECTION', DefQ)  is how I select by strings. One other possibility, have you copied the code from Outlook, Word etc.. these programs change the character symbol of the quotes to a more visually appealing form which no longer works in python (or C or VB.net or C++ and probably many more).

Comment: I triple-checked my whole code yesterday again and I do not know why, but now it works. It works too with the different ways I tried to make the query statement. Thanks a lot for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using AddFieldDelimiters:

```
import arcpy

features = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\featureclass'

whereClause = """"{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=features, field="Fruit"), "Apple")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=features, out_layer='templyr', whereClause=whereClause)
```

Now `'templyr'` will be a feature layer created using your whereClause.

Or you can use MakeFeatureLayer without a whereClause and Select by attributes with the feature layer as input.